# How to automate creation of JMeter scripts?

Tags: automation, jmeter, performance-testing

There are CRUD performance tests that are exposed through a rest API which takes in test name as a parameter. Every time a new test is created, a new JMeter file must be created to hit this endpoint. I cannot use one Jmeter script to run all tests because the reporting framework that consumes the JMeter output, takes a single Jmeter file to display the output - Jmeter fileName Vs Time. The configurations of the JMeter scripts are all same except for three parameters. Is there a way to automate the creation of JMeter scripts?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can just parameterize a single JMeter file to take 3 parameters which can be passed via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) when you launch the test and read in JMeter via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) so for example:

- if you run your test like `jmeter -Jfoo=bar -n -t test.jmx`
- you will be able to access this `bar` value as `${__P(foo,)}` where required in the script

similarly for other parameters.

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: No, so the problem is the JMeter files are consumed by a reporting framework which expects separate Jmeter file for each test case hardcoded parameters. So can I write a selenium script that can create a JMeter file? or are there other ways to automate this creation of Jmeter files.